# node express hogan partials nesting

Tags: node.js, express, nested, templating

Firstly, I'm new to web development. I'm using node and express server, with hogan-express for html rendering.

I have the following template html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <div id="content">
      <!-- Place changing page content here -->
      {{> part }}
    </div>
    <footer>
      {{date}}
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to use another partial, say part1.html, in parts.html, which itself is used as a partial in template.

How to pass this part1 to parts?

Please help.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use EJS template engine for serving dynamic HTML